# How to pass an object and access methods?

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to issue commands to a database but I want to have the ability to connect to different ones (eg. SQL Express, PostgreSQL, SQLite)

I have a setting that tells the application which database is being used, but the syntax for the SQL code is slightly different so I have a class for Postgres and a class for SQLite. What I want to do is define the same methods in different classes and pass the class. I've written this:

```
public static class DatabaseConnection
{
    public static string PostgreSQLConnectionString { get; set; }
    public static string SQLiteConnectionString { get; set; }

    public static object Interface(string connectiontype)
    {
        switch (connectiontype)
        {
            case "PostgreSQL":
                PostgresConnection postgresConnection = new PostgresConnection();
                return postgresConnection;
            case "SQLite":
                SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection();
                return sqliteConnection;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which I then want to reference like:

```
Object Connection = DatabaseConnection.Interface("PostgreSQL");
Connection.Connect()
```

Where the method `Connect()` exists in all classes. This of course doesn't work since the class isn't directly named so I can't call methods that may not exist. I'm currently getting around this by copying all the methods into the `DatabaseConnection` class and using switch statements in every method. Is there a better way to accomplish the same effect?

Comment: You need to read about inheritance and interfaces in C#.

Comment: And also read up on dependency injection (also known as "Inversion of Control" or IOC)

Comment: Why don't you use the [DbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2) class as your return type, which all connection types inherit from (AFAIK).

Comment: And you shouldn't use static field and methods

Comment: There are many terms for what you are doing. One of them is a "Data layer" is a way to abstract database specific into a more generic which allow you to change the database whenever you want. You would want to look into interface as @S.Akbari suggested.

Comment: Not as important as reading up on inheritance/interfaces; but you should also read up on how to avoid [stringly typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `Factory` pattern to create the instance, and an `interface` to implement the connection:

```
public interface IConnection
{
    void Connect();
}
public class PostgresConnection : IConnection
{
    public void Connect()
    {
    ...
    }
}
public class SqliteConnection : IConnection
{
    public void Connect()
    {
    ...
    }
}

public static class DatabaseConnectionFactory
{
    public static string PostgreSQLConnectionString { get; set; }
    public static string SQLiteConnectionString { get; set; }

    public static IConnection Create(string connectiontype)
    {
        switch (connectiontype)
        {
            case "PostgreSQL":
                PostgresConnection postgresConnection = new PostgresConnection();
                return postgresConnection;
            case "SQLite":
                SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection();
                 return sqliteConnection;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But, I would recommend you look at something like EntityFramework or Dapper, both of which will be much easier to write for as they support many/all the database types you could ever hope to use.

Comment: I think  this approach can violate the open-close principle (because of using switch-case, what if you want to add another connection for example to SQL Express, you need to change your class and switch-case!). I think it would be better to allows subclasses to decide how the instantiation process will be completed. i.e you delegate the object creation to the subclasses that implement the factory method to create objects.

Comment: I agree @S.Akbari but as the OP sounds like a beginner, perhaps sticking to simpler things at this time would be easier.

Comment: @Neil that's exactly what i tough you were aiming for when i saw your answer.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the answer, I'm currently looking into EntityFramework but it'll take me a while to understand. I'm glad I'm aware of this now. In the meantime your solution is definitely the answer to my question so I've marked as solved. I don't forsee an issue with open-close for the switch-case as I won't have an obscene amount of DBs but adding more methods could be tedious.

Comment: @RyanD.  The open-close principle is not only a concern for now, but also for future. It says **an entity should be open for extension, but closed for modification** that should be considered serious!

Comment: @Neil And got upvote from me for using Design Pattern to solve the OP's challenge, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create `IRepository` interface that will define all database operation and then different implementation for different databases or few interfaces for example `IUserRepository`, `IWorkRepository` etc.
Polymorphism is better then use switch - your db client can rely on interface and you can add additional implementations using another databases.